# Blocking kernel updates with dpkg

Tags: kernel, apt

I'd like to block all distribution-shipped kernel updates due to a [nasty thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63198/5614) that recently happened to me. (I'm on a Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 derivative.)

I'd like to block all updates to installed kernels of the minor version 3.2 to the `linux-headers`, `linux-headers-generic`, `linux-image`, and `linux-image-extra` packages. The problem I'm encountering is that these all have a version and if I block a specific version, nothing is gained because a new version will be installed (eg: if I block `linux-image-3.2.0-35`, `linux-image-3.2.0-36` is not blocked and could still potentially be installed with a `dist-upgrade` from `apt`.)

Comment: Note that this no longer works in Ubuntu 16.04. You need to blacklist packages using this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you need to use is a feature of apt-get called [holding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Holding_Packages)

You can either do this via Synaptic or Dpkg, Here is how I would hold my kernel using the dpkg method.

First check your kernel image name

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

output for me:

```
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64              3.2.35-2                           amd64        Linux 3.2 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                      3.2+46                             amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

then tell dpkg to hold the metapackage (the generic version without any version numbers)

```
echo linux-image-amd64 hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

You can then check this worked via `dpkg -l linux-image-amd64`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-==========================================================
hi  linux-image-amd64          3.2+46             amd64              Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

Notice the 'hi' at the bottom, h means held and i means currently installed. This package is installed but **will not** be upgraded.

You can reverse this via

```
echo linux-image-amd64 install | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

and again can check via `dpkg -l linux-image-amd64`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-==========================================================
ii  linux-image-amd64          3.2+46             amd64              Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

Notice 'ii', the first i means this package is set to install and the second i means it is currently installed. This package is installed and **will** be upgraded.

For more information on these flags see `man dpkg` specifically the 'package selection states' sections.

Comment: My image names are [here](http://pastebin.com/B41AL9EN). Do I want to ban "linux-image-generic"?

Comment: @TKKocheran yes; you want to place a hold on the metapackage, rather than a specific version.

Comment: Does not work - dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 1: linux-image-amd64
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database
is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method;
please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>